# like with present perfect

Tags: present-perfect

I have never seen" **like** " with present perfect  why ?

Is it possible to say I **have liked** that book or should I say I liked that book 
for me these have different meaning first one I still like it and second it is the past it doesnot give any info we don't know if I like it

Answer (score 1):

You would use present perfect *like* if you are saying you regularly or more than once liked something that happened in the past, and plan to do it again.

> A: So I hear you like sherbet.
>
> B: That's true.
>
> A: Did you ever have the orange sherbet at Johnny's Icecream Shop?
>
> B: I used to.  All the time.  I've liked that a lot.  It's been awhile but I think I'm going to go tomorrow.

Non-perfect *like* will work too.  But *have liked*  won't work if there isn't or can't be a plan to do it again, such as below.

> A: So I hear you like sherbet.
>
> B: That's true.
>
> A: Did you ever have the orange sherbet at Johnny's Icecream Shop?  It's a shame the place burned down and no longer exists.
>
> B: I used to.  All the time.  I liked that a lot.  What a pity.

Comment: so if I use past simple that obligatory means that I don't like it now or it depends on the context In your example when B says "I liked it a lot " he still likes it

Comment: @user5577 Yeh, Past Simple is mostly about the past. Of course one might say something like "**I liked that car**" and not mean that he doesn't like it now. Present Perfect with *like* simply shares past enjoynesses with the listener in the meaning of "**tasted**" or "**tried**" for instance.

Comment: As a matter of fact if you wish to say that somebody liked something just now, in the present, or just merely before you said it, you can use the Past Simple. "**Give the dog some sausage. - Here you are boy - Oh, look he liked that (the dog enjoyed the food just now)**" However, I met that in several sources, last of which is the Fallout 4 game, it's still correct to use either the Past Simple or the Present Simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is uncommon to see the verb *like* used in the present perfect because it is not usually necessary, or its meaning could be ambiguous. If you currently like something then the **simple present** is used, and if you used to like something (but don't anymore) then the **simple past** can be used.

That doesn't mean that you *can't* use it with the present perfect (or any other perfect for that matter). For example, you can use it if you want to say *how long* you **have liked** something for (*I have liked football for as long as I can remember*), or in the subjunctive mood to say that you **would have liked** to have done something, had you been given the opportunity (*I would have liked to have met Gandhi*).